# Swift subscript setter that accepts a different type than the getter's return value

Tags: swift, swift-subscript

I have a custom collection that can receive values of any type and converts them to strings. For example:

```
collection["key"] = 10
let value = collection["key"] // value is a String
```

Is there a way to do this? I tried implementing two subscript methods but Swift doesn't support write-only subscripts.

```
subscript(key: String) -> String {
  get { ... }
}

// Doesn't compile
subscript(key: String) -> AnyObject {
  set { ... }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it. [File a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) if this is important to you, but more likely this just won't fly and you'll need a different design. (Note that a property can't have different setter and getter types either.)

Comment: Why can't you also use other types for the getter? The getter can convert the values to strings before using them to get the value out of the container. It makes much more sense to be able to get a value back out using the key you used to put it in.

Comment: I'm wrapping an existing Apple API that does this. The Obj-C signatures for -[objectForKeyedSubscript:] and -[setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] differ in the types they use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two different `subscript` implementations and disable the getter for one of them:

```
subscript(key: String) -> String {
    get { return "howdy" } // put real implementation here
}
subscript(key: String) -> AnyObject {
    get { fatalError("Oooops") }
    set { }
}
```

However, this still leaves open the question of how to distinguish between these two `subscript` calls in context. It would be better to give them different signatures through their external parameter names:

```
subscript(key: String) -> String {
    get { return "howdy" } // put real implementation here
}
subscript(# any: String) -> AnyObject {
    get { fatalError("Oooops") }
    set { }
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
let m = MyClass()
m[any:"thing"] = 1
println(m["thing"]) // "1", presumably
```

Comment: thx for answer. Did you know, does swift 5 has the same solution?

Answer (score 0):

Define subscript to return `AnyObject` (or `Any` as needed) and at the point you use the getter cast the result to `String`.  You may already need to deal with `subscript` returning an optional so the coercion is just all part of extracting your desired value.

```
if let value = collection["key"] as String { ... }
else {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define your own type and make it conform to the `IntegerLiteralConvertible` and the `StringLiteralConvertible` protocols.

Technically you could also write an extension for String to make it conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible` but that might get confusing, since it will be available in your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem here and I solved it using a generic type for my variable and returning the type I want on its getter. You can try doing something like this:

```
class StorageClass {
  private var _value: String?
  public var value: Any? {
    set {
      if let num = newValue as? Int {
        self._value = String(format: "%d",num)
      }
    }
    get {
      return self._value
    }
  }
}
```

By doing this, it is possible to do something like:

```
var storage = StorageClass()
storage.value = 10 /* setting value as an Integer */
let aString = storage.value as! String /* receiving a String value back */
```